# Drools condition for when fact exists or does not exist

Tags: drools

I'm trying to set up a drools rule that would achieve something like this:

```
rule "Rule 1"
    salience 100
    activation-group "..."
when
    $fact: Fact exists, or fact does not exist
then
    if $fact exists then do X. Else, do Y.
```

I know I can do this by having two different rules, one for when the fact exists, and one for when the fact does not exist. Is there any way I can combine these conditions into one? For the when statement, I have tried:

```
$fact: Fact() || not Fact()
```

which didn't work. Is there a correct way to write the "when" statement in drools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we revert to boolean logic, `A || !A` is the same as `true` so you can omit the condition entirely.

You're already doing this correctly. Rule 1: if X exists, then do A(). Rule 2: if X does not exist, then do B(). That is the *correct* way to do things:

```
rule "Fact exists"
when
  exists(Fact())
then
  doX()
end

rule "Fact does not exist"
when 
  not(Fact())
then
  doY()
end
```

That's good rule design and how you should do this. I can't think of a good reason to compress it into one rule. If you can clarify a legitimate use case for why you'd want to collapse it into a single rule, it might be possible to give a better or more concrete response.

You may be able to abuse [conditional and named consequences](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-THEN-advanced-con_drl-rules) for this, though it's definitely not designed for this (nor recommended.)

Comment: That's true. Basically, I have a bunch of conditions for different facts in this rule, and some complicated logic in the "then" section. I want to do slightly different things in the "then" section based on whether or not a new fact is present. Having to create two rules for this would lead to a lot of code duplication, and I'd rather be able to just do a simple "if fact is present then do X, else do Y" within this rule.

Comment: You probably should be moving that complicated logic out of the then section and either into the when (if they're conditionals ... side benefit will be to speed up processing) or into functions that you can call from the RHS of multiple rules as needed.

Comment: What @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas is saying is totally correct. Keep the when and the then part as small as possible and you get all the benefits from the rule system